# Layered elements firing 2 events with one touch - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular for a mobile web project.  I have a basic share button, when clicked a share modal pops up.  The share modal's Close button lays on top of (higher z-index) the actual share button.  The share modal is generated from external HTML so I cannot use an ng-click directive.  As a work around I use the following:

```
document.querySelector('#shareContent .shareClose').addEventListener('touchend', function( e ){

    e.stopPropagation();
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.showShareOverlay = false;
    })
    console.log("closing the share", $scope.showShareOverlay)
})
```

My issue is that when I touchend the .shareClose button, the modal closes for a brief moment before showing again.  Somehow the touch event is being transferred to the below share button to launch the modal again.  Is there anyway to prevent the event from bleeding through to the share button?

Comment: this should work without stopping event propagation. Can you conduct an experiment without angular and see this behavior is caused by the framework?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the Android stock browser. Whatever was underneath the close button for my modal would also get clicked shortly after tapping the close button.

Using the [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library on the app stopped this behaviour from happening, presumably due to the specific way it handles click events.